# IONIC/Angular 2: Cookie based auth (With headers)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have the code below to pass a cookie header to an endpoint however the REST call fails with an error (But the error is null).. Can anyone see an issue with the call i have below?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import {InAppBrowser} from 'ionic-native';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ThemeableBrowser } from 'ionic-native';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-contact',
      templateUrl: 'contact.html'
    })
    export class ContactPage {

      constructor(private http: Http) {

      }



  launchTheme(url){

var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Cookie', 'HQ9VVdTJnJlcXVlc3RUbXN0bXA9MjAxNy0wMi0xNFQxOCUzQTQ0JTNBMzImdXNlcklkPSZwYWdlPTEmc3RhcnQ9MCZsaW1pdD0yNQ%3D%3D; CTSESSION=AAAAAgABAFhYyvOIo1rGqfd4fcbFvbxrwSCaYNMhCKtp5PJvq08KEn0890EoJrMjezIENjxp2ZEltDG4uUzdO79H2lk2kur2%2FdZu6%2FCRNvN5kztICTsEBCQ9qjjZHgAM');
 this.http.get('http://tespapi.com', {
    headers: headers
    })
    .map(res => res.text())
    .subscribe(
      data =>  console.log(data),
      err =>  console.log(err),

    );

  }

}
```

Comment: Cannot say about reason. But best way for you to proceed is to open developer tools in browser and check "request/response" that was sent to network. And after that (if everything is OK) check backend handling of cookies.

Comment: thanks laser will do...

Comment: I don't believe that we are allowed to set Cookie from the mobile browser. Please confirm.

Comment: @MarkPhilipD'santos you can, cookies are working just fine. With ionic2 the only problem was that `ionic serve` command starts "http" server, which does not sent cookies in my case, but worked perfectly fine on android.

Comment: @laser. Sorry. My bad